# Talend using elasticsearch with component tElasticsearchIndex

Tags: elasticsearch, talend

I'm new in Talend DI I'm developping a job in order to index data inside Elasticsearch using an inputfile

I'm using for this Talend data integration

I found a tutorial that explain an external component tElasticsearchIndex to index data

see this [link](http://spring-webservice-2-step-by-step.blogspot.in/2014/01/talend-elasticsearch-indexing-tutorial.html)

all steps are ok but I got an error java linked to two method from classes (Settings , TransportClient)

```
The method settingsBuilder() is undefined for the type Settings
The method builder() is undefined for the type TransportClient
```

[error java code after adding component tElasticsearchIndex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyBn.png)

[design tElasticsearchIndex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni33G.png)

I tried to import the two libraries (that I had aldready added in routines) with component tJava (Advanced Settings) I have always the same errors

If some one can help me please

I using talend 6.1.2

thank you

Comment: Try adding your libraries using `tLibraryLoad` component (one component for each library)

Comment: what do you mean by one component fr each library please ?

Comment: I added two tLibrayLiad for elasticsearch and lucene-core always same problem

Comment: I meant to say you can't add all your libraries using just one tLibraryLoad (in case you weren't familiar with it).

Comment: I think there is a problem with version of my elasticsearch v5 and component tElasticsearchIndex !